# Extension of a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let X and Y Hausdorff normal topological spaces, and let N,M dense subspaces of X,Y, respectivaly.

Let f a homeomorphism between N and M. Is true that exists an continuos extension F (between X and Y) of f?

F may also be a homeomorphism between X and Y?

Comment: No. A counterexample is $X=\mathbb{R}$, $Y=\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ \sqrt{2} \}$, $N=M= \mathbb{Q} $, $f=id_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Then $f$ cannot be extended because we should have $F(\sqrt{2}) = \sqrt{2} \notin Y$

Comment: This is probably true if $X$ and $Y$ are compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is No, even if $X$ and $Y$ are compact.

Let $X = S^1$, $M$ be $S^1\setminus\{p\}$, that is , $M$ is $S^1$ with a point removed.  Let  $Y =[0,1]$  and $N = (0,1)$.

Obviously, $M$ and $N$ are homeomorphic, so let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be such a homeomorphism.

Then there is no continuous extension $F:X\rightarrow Y$.  This follows because $F(p)$ is forced to simultaneously be $0$ and $1$ by continuity.

This example can also be used to show that $F$, if it exists, needs not be a homeomorphism:  Let $g:N\rightarrow M$ be a homeomorphism.  Then there is a (unique) extension $G$ and $G$ has the property that $G(0) =G(1) = p$.  In particular, $G$ is not injective, so not a homeomorphism.

(On the other hand $G$ *will* be surjective, and this must happen in the compact case:  $G(Y)$ must be compact, being the image of a compact space, so is closed because $X$ is Hausdorff.  But $G(Y)$ contains the dense set $M$, so $X = \overline{M}\subseteq \overline{G(Y)} = G(Y)$, so $X\subseteq G(Y)$.)